# How do i replace something in array using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have got this jquery array

```
var left=[1,2,3,4];
```

And i want to replace `3` element with `7`.

Comment: Use for loop and an if statement. You are good to go.

Comment: Well what if i do not know what is inside of array? @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: `var left=[1,2,3,4]; left.forEach(function(val,i){ this[i] = val == 3 ? 7 : val; }, left);`

Comment: You want to replace the element that *is* `3`, or the the element that is third in the array? If the former do you want to replace the first occurrence, the last occurrence of all occurrences?

Comment: that is 3 @DavidThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function here. Try this:

```
var left = [1,2,3,4];

result = left.map(function(item) { 
    return item == 3? 7: item;
});
```